# Click on the already selected segment control swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an `UISegmentedControl` with 4 segments. When it is selected, it should pop up view. And when the pop up dismissed, and trying to click on same segment index it should again show the pop up. By using following does not have any action on click of same segment index after pop up dissmissed.

```
segHeader.addTarget(self, action: Selector("valuechange:"), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

or

```
segHeader.addTarget(self, action: Selector("valuechange:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Comment: only one time (When value changes) its firing, on second time click its not firing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of research am able to solve it.

Am writing answer here may it will be helpfull to others in future.

when the segment controll is pressed write below code.

@IBAction func segHeaderPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

if segHeader.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

```
        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
            if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
                view.backgroundColor = iOSBlueColor // UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
        }
```

selectedInd = -1

//your code ...
 }else if(segHeader.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

```
        let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
            if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
                view.backgroundColor = iOSBlueColor //UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
        }
```

// your code ...
}else if(segHeader.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){

let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

```
        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
            if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
                view.backgroundColor = iOSBlueColor //UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
        }
```

}else if(segHeader.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){

let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

```
        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
            if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
                view.backgroundColor = iOSBlueColor //UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
        }
```

}
}

basically segmented controll functionality is once it is selected if you tap again same it will not respond. so am just changing the background colors of selected segment.  hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UISegmentedControl` and override `touchesEnded`

```
class DemoSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged);
            super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event);
    }
}
```

This has a bug, when touching different segments it will trigger twice your action for `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged` but when touching same segment multiple time it will behave as expected. You can try to "filter" events using timestamp, if triggering action twice is too expensive for you.

Comment: sorry am new to ios as well to swift, can you tell me i should i link my segment control to this class and how should i call the method on segment control click

Comment: select segment control from your xib or storyboard, then open Identity inspector from left pane, see 'Custom Class' field and type the name of custom class, for above will be DemoSegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to pop/show a view when a segmented control is selected right?

SWIFT 3

In that case, you are overcomplicating things, is much easier to use:

viewName.isHidden =  false/true

This way you can hide or show  the view/views base on the action applied to a segmented control index. For example:

@IBAction func segmentedAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

```
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        viewName.isHidden = false

    }
    else {

        viewName.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry understood it wrong, by the way found answer for this, i will update.

Answer (score 1):

I improve tesla's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516261/6709130) little bit.

If you send `.touchUpInside` event and bind it instead of `.valueChanged`, it triggered just one time in each situation.

Furthermore, you should call `sendActions` function after `touchesEnded`.
If not, `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` will return old value.

```swift
class ClickableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event);
    self.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside);
  }
}
```